# How to parse more than 30k emailbodys

Tags: pandas, dataframe, email, outlook, powerquery

I am using MS Excel Enterprise and connected via Exchange Server to Outlook and got all the E-Mails via Power Query and their respective Body (Body.TextBody). Now I have an excel file with over 15k rows and the E-Mails are not sent in any particular form. I need to process all of them.

The first step is to clean each of the Body so that only the last reply is left. Afterwards I'd want to remove any names of employees (I have an list with all names) if it is in the list.

So i converted the excel file to an csv file and then read it via pandas. Now I'm trying to use different kind of functions but it doesn't work. As an example I'dlike to use a function from the library email_reply_parser. If I try to use any functions with apply() on my column it doesn't work. I feel like I misunderstood something completely wrong about it and I tackled the problem in the wrong way?

I had different errors like

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Am I even on the correct path for this task`?

Comment: Seems like you are sending wrong params to the function you are trying to apply. Can you share some code examples?

Comment: I think it could have been due to not doing some data cleaning. Im going to sleep now, but im gonna drop tomorrow all the null values, because there is no other way there should be any float types in my email body. I feel like the functions should work afterwards.